# Как закодировать POST запрос в формате URL-encoded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

Я делаю оплату с помощью merchant001 API. При попытке создания транзакции API выдаёт ошибку:
`Cannot destructure property 'amount' of '(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)`. В документации написано:

- Тело запроса необходимо передавать в формате URL-encoded
- --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Вот мой код:

```py
import requests

head = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer API TOKEN",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

body = {
  "isPartnerFee": True,
  "pricing": {
    "local": {
      "amount": 301,
      "currency": "RUB"
    }
  },
  "selectedProvider": {
    "type": "VTB",
    "method": "CARD"
  },
}

print(requests.post("https://api.merchant001.io/v1/transaction/merchant", headers=head, json=body).json())
```

Comment: Чтобы было x-www-form-urlencoded, нужно body как словарь передать через параметр data, а через json. Но насколько я помню, так можно только простой словарь без глубокой вложенности можно передать. В целом по ошибке похоже, что проблема не в коде, а в данных, что-то типа того, что нельзя amount перезаписать.